# Angular 9 - How to choose child component at run-time?

Tags: angular, components, containers

I'd like to build a component which takes a configuration object.  This component has a certain HTML structure with some buttons and whatnot.  But in the middle of this container structure is a placeholder where I'd like to embed another component that is based on a 'type' field in the config object.

So for example if I have this input in my component:

```
@Input() config: { type: string };
```

My HTML for this component is something like:

```
<div>
  <span>Common text</span>
  <div>
    Common div structure here
  </div>
  <div * placeholder for component based on 'config.type' * />
  <div>
    Common div structure here
  </div>
  <button>Clear</button>
  <button>Apply</button>
</div>
```

What's the best way to provide that HTML for the placeholder?  One option I thought of is with *ngIf, but it seems kind of ugly:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="config.type === 'type1'">
  <type-1 [inputs]/>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="config.type === 'type2'">
  <type-2 [inputs]/>
</ng-container>
...
```

Another is to do it with templates:

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="templateRef" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ input: [inputs]}">
</ng-container>
...
<ng-template #type1>
  <type-1 [inputs]>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #type2>
  <type-2 [inputs]>
</ng-template>
```

But if done that way, when's the best time to update the 'templateRef' member in the code with the view child?

Is there a better more "Angular" way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can also consider using [ngSwitch](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch). Also config.type probably should be some enum.